# Why use svg for text logo?

Tags: html, css, svg

I just started to learn svg. One thing perplexes me is I find some site use svg/path to draw a text logo. Like this one:http://www.desiringgod.org/

The logo is pretty simple itself, however, the SVG it is using contain a horrendous `<path>` tag where there are lots of numbers.

I understand that with SVG we can scale the logo, but I don't see any difference if this logo is based on a .png file. So what really is the benefit?

Secondly, I don' think something like

```
<path d="M115.326252,8.93098333 L115.326252,16.3798167 L113.923083,16.3798167 L113.923083,14.96265 L113.878305,14.96265 C113.092947,16.0569833 111.560896,16.5939833 109.858654,16.5939833 C106.367752,16.5939833 103.855367,14.0609833 103.855367,8.63131667 C103.855367,3.20098333 106.367752,0.667483333 109.858654,0.667483333 C112.454152,0.667483333 114.454146,1.91331667 115.390858,5.21765 L113.771894,5.53931667 C113.007521,3.07148333 111.7296,2.12731667 109.943088,2.1273166 ....</path>
```

is written by human being. This must be generated by something, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of using `SVG` logos over `PNG` logos are the following:

- Scale to any size, perfect for responsive websites.
- Look sharp on retina displays.
- Don't lose clarity, except for very tiny sizes (same with PNG).

With PNG files you would most likely need to generate multiple resolution versions of the same image and hope that the original image is large enough to support the future display resolutions (8K for example).

And yes, the path is not written by a human being. [It's a standard part of an SVG file](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). You could also do stuff like export SVG files as HTML5 canvas code with an `ink2canvas` extension in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of SVG:

- Resolution Independence
- Super-Accessible DOM Node-Based API
- No Unnecessary HTTP Requests
- Easy Interactive Scripting

Read more details on: [Why Aren’t You Using SVG?](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/why-arent-you-using-svg--net-25414)

Answer (score 0):

> SVG offers a way to do full resolution graphical elements, no matter
>   what size screen, what zoom level, or what resolution your user's
>   device has.

So you write HTML? JavaScript? CSS? Good. Then you already know a lot of what you need to know to get writing SVG.

SVG actually uses an XML-compatible format to define its rendering shapes. Beyond this, you can actually style shapes in CSS, and make them interactive with JavaScript. Multiple JS libraries exist to assist you in this world, like D3.js and Raphael. Here's an example of an SVG element group (the Envato leaf).

The other benefit of SVG is,
When you use images in an html document with the  tag, you are defining a file that the user's browser will request. This request will take up bandwidth and require more precious time to download. If your image is instead a set of dom nodes, it cuts that extra HTTP request out, making your website faster and more user friendly.

An SVG XML document of any complexity looks relatively archaic and complicated, and seemingly isn't nearly as easy as just using an image.

Answer (score 0):

In here, I will describe some differences between using SVG and PNG from an application perspective:

1. SVG files are lighter than PNG files when deployed to your
   application.
2. PNG is more efficient as far as UI responsiveness since the file is
   already within your application, and there is no scaling needed, but it's heavier than your SVG file.
3. PNG gives a better focus to photographs or detailed images than SVG.

I personally use **SVG for icons and logos** and **PNG for photographs or detailed images**.